# Ionic: How to change the CSS of span.button-inner in the Shadow DOM

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-button` with an `ion-icon` inside. I have been able to access the button in the Shadow DOM with `ion-button::part(native)`, but the `ion-icon` is currently very small due to the `flex-direction` being set to `row` instead of `column` within the `span.button-inner` element contained in the `ion-button`. Here's what I can view with inspect element:

```
.button-inner {
display: flex;
position: relative;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
flex-shrink: 0;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Changing the `flex-flow` to `column` instead of `row` in my browser works, but I can't access it within my CSS file, since it doesn't have a `::part()` I can reference like the `ion-button`:

```
#shadow-root (open)
  <button type="button" class="button-native" part="native">
    <span class="button-inner">...</span>
    ...
  </button>
```

I've tried several different things in my CSS, like

```
ion-button::part(native) span.button-inner {
  flex-direction: column !important;
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<ion-button id="notes" size="large" (click)="onNotesClick()">
    <ion-icon id="notes-icon" name="document-text-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```